# Problem in getting data from Table functions

Tags: sql-server

I want my function to return a A table with some values

I must fix something in the update but I don't know what. 
Below is my function `FngetTableH` definiton,

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FnGetTableH] 
 (
  @Date DateTime 
  )
  RETURNS  @Listeab_ Table(CLOSING_PRICE money,IdValeur int)
 AS
  BEGIN

    Insert @Listeab_
   (          CLOSING_PRICE ,IdValeur)

     select Distinct 0 , IdValeur
     From Historique



     Update @Listeab_
       Set CLOSING_PRICE = (Select  CLOSING_PRICE
       from Historique H
      inner join (Select MAX(@Date) As DATEDU,IdValeur FROM Historique
  where 
     DATE_NEGO<= @Date 
       group by IdValeur ) L2
       on 
  H.DATE_NEGO=L2.DATEDU
     and
  H.IdValeur=L2.IdValeur
       )
  return 
 END
```

when i Execute this code

```
declare @Date date = '10/09/2013'

---select*from FnGetTableH(@Date)
select  C.IdClient,H.IdValeur,C.RaisonSocial,SUM( case I.sens 
                                                   WHEN 'c' then  + I.Qantite
                                                   WHEN'd' then  - I.Qantite
                                                  END) as 'Solde', H.closing_price
from Imputations I
Inner join FnGetTableH(@Date) H
on H.IdValeur=I.IdValeur 
Inner join Clients C
on C.IdClient=I.IdClient
where I.DateImputation=@Date    
group by C.IdClient,RaisonSocial,H.closing_price,H.IdValeur
Order by IdClient asc
```

Error I get is,

> Msg 512, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne 4 La sous-requête a retourné
>   plusieurs valeurs. Cela n'est pas autorisé quand la sous-requête suit
>   =, !=, <, <= , >, >= ou quand elle est utilisée en tant qu'expression. L'instruction a été arrêtée.

English translation:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 The subquery returned multiple
>   values. This is not allowed when the subquery follows =,! =, <, <=,>,>
>   = Or when it is used as an expression. The instruction has been stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your `CLOSING_PRICE` in update statement give more then one records, try `top 1` in your query.

Try this:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FnGetTableH] 
     (
      @Date DateTime 
      )
      RETURNS  @Listeab_ Table(CLOSING_PRICE money,IdValeur int)
     AS
      BEGIN

        Insert @Listeab_
       (          CLOSING_PRICE ,IdValeur)

         select Distinct 0 , IdValeur
         From Historique



         Update @Listeab_
           Set CLOSING_PRICE = (Select top 1  CLOSING_PRICE
           from Historique H
          inner join (Select MAX(@Date) As DATEDU,IdValeur FROM Historique
      where 
         DATE_NEGO<= @Date 
           group by IdValeur ) L2
           on 
      H.DATE_NEGO=L2.DATEDU
         and
      H.IdValeur=L2.IdValeur
           )
      return 
     END
```